# SQL request from 2 different databases with same structure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 really similar databases, with exact same structure (one of them is a backup of the other so some values changed which is why they are similar but not the exact same).

So here is what I would like to do, taking value from database 2 and updating database 1 with it (so it will allow me later to backup some data from a certain user without having to do it all manually or to backup everyone)

```
UPDATE s 
SET 
    t1.column=t2.column 
FROM database1.table1 t1 
JOIN database2.table1 t2 
WHERE t1.table2='test' 
    AND t2.table2='test'
```

I tried something like this but it didn't work, both database are in a same server and "next to each others", also names are different, so I wanted to know if what I try to do is possible or not

Comment: "But it didn't work"? What does this mean? Too many updates? Too few? An error with some error message? The computer exploded? There is an `ON` clause missing for the join.

Comment: what do you mean taking 'value' from database 2 and updating database 1? You want to update multiple tables?Or just one with store transaction for example?

Comment: I have an ID that links all tables, so I want to update someone by updating the values in the current database using the data from the backup database, so I can use a backup of anyone to implement it in current server (instead of entering values manually or backup all users)

Comment: Also the message happening is "Ambiguous column name 'column1'. "

Comment: What is `s`?  I think this is just a typo.

Comment: s was table's name I used, but ya in this case here it was a typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If table's name is Test, then try this query for Update (instead of key, place column primary key of table) :

```
 Update database1.dbo.test
 Set 
 database1.dbo.test.Column=t2.Column
    From
    (Select Column,Key from database2.dbo.test) t2
    Join database1.dbo.test t1
    On t2.Key=t1.Key
```

Or

```
UPDATE pereger.dbo.characters
   SET  
   pereger.dbo.characters.level=t2.level FROM
   (SELECT level,characterId FROM 
   peregercopy.dbo.characters) t2 
   JOIN pereger.dbo.characters t1 ON 
   t2.characterID=t1.characterId
   WHERE t2.characterId=5
```

Comment: The select part is wrong (it shows red waves under the column names or even the db.dbo.tableName)

Comment: Please, type you current query. Do you type you primary key instead of my column key?

Comment: Also the message happening is "Ambiguous column name 'column1'. "

Comment: I adapted everything to match my database name, table name, column name and key name, so it should work, it works for the main server but didn't recognize the backupserver being an older copy of the main database

Comment: ```UPDATE t1
SET t1.level=t2.level
FROM
(SELECT level,characterId FROM peregercopy.dbo.characters) t2
JOIN pereger.dbo.characters t1
ON t2.characterID=t1.characterId
WHERE t2.characterId=5```

Comment: Select Column,Key from database2.dbo.test

Comment: here is the query I use with all the correct names of column, table, database and key

Comment: table name is characters, key is characterId, column is level, and databases are pereger and peregercopy

Comment: I have changed little my query, run it, please

Comment: Try changed query

Comment: I feel like it worked, but SQL server management studio still show red waves saying it isn't correct, but working, thanks you